# Efficient and safe passing of immutable objects between threads in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

Given the situation where a `Producer Thread` creates an object `o` of an arbitrary type `O` that then must be read (and only read) by a `Consumer Thread`, which is the ideal way to accomplish this in an efficient and thread safe way in C++11?

As of now my implementation relies on a producer-consumer model, using a mutexed/conditioned work queue based on a template:

```
template<typename T> class WorkQueue {
    std::list<T> queue;
    std::mutex mut;
    std::condition_variable cond;

public:
    ...
}
```

If `o`'s type is defined as follows:

```
class WorkItem {
    const int value;
public:
    WorkItem(int v) : value(v) {}

    const int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and the threads produce-consume `WorkItem` objects in the heap like this:

```
WorkQueue<WorkItem*> workQueue;
...

void producerThread() {
    workQueue.add(new WorkItem(0));
}

void consumerThread() {
    WorkItem *item = workQueue.remove();
    doSomething(item.getValue());
    delete item;
}
```

Am I guaranteed that the heap objects will be properly readable by the consumer?

If the answer happens to be no, I'm guessing that WorkItem's members should be protected by a mutex, but that would be quite an inefficient solution, as no locks should be required after the WorkItem has been made available to all the threads. Alternatively, I'm guessing that an atomization based approach could be better in this case.

Comment: How large are your WorkItems actually going to be, and how many per second do you envision needing to process?

Comment: In the problem I'm trying to solve, I'm expecting for the WorkItems to contain vectors of ints, with sizes ranging from single digits to the thousands, with the items with larger arrays taking a significant time to be processed (a few hundred ms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you propose looks OK.  You might store smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<WorkItem>` to gain exception safety if e.g. `doSomething()` throws.  And you should be aware of lock-free queues, but you do not necessarily need to use one, especially if it would mean adding new library dependencies to your project.  Finally, all that `new` memory allocation may someday be a bottleneck, in which case look into using an object pool or otherwise reusing your WorkItems.  But most of those things would be premature optimizations right now.

Comment: I'm curious, however, on what guarantees the readability of the object that the producer created to the consumer. Is it the fact that its pointer was stored within a mutexed list?

Comment: I don't see anything that would make it unreadable.  You'd have to modify the object or delete it, or corrupt memory in your program in general, otherwise it's fine.  This is sort of like asking why Windows Vista is able to browse the Internet--is it because it comes with a TCP stack?

Comment: Let me rephrase my concern. What exactly guarantees the synchronization of the producer's and consumer's processor caches upon the creation of the object?

Comment: The processor caches?  That's your concern?  I suppose to have a full explanation of why it is guaranteed might take a Master's degree in computer science followed by one in electrical engineering.  I don't know how to explain it in 500 characters or less in any way that will sound like a "guarantee."  It's just sort of how mutexes, the C language, pthreads, and common modern micro-architectures work.

Comment: I'll take it as it being guaranteed, therefore question answered. But I'm definitely curious about what's exactly guaranteeing that in this case. The allocation of a new object in the heap will indeed incur synchronization to manage the free heap space (and you already pointed it as being a bottleneck). But I'm guessing that in addition to reserving the necessary space, the `new` operator also synchronizes the addresses containing the values left by the constructor.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is cache coherency.  It's a property of the hardware and firmware on most systems.  It's not handled by the software, in `new` or elsewhere.